# Fastest way to return all triangles from array of points

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a number of points in array `arr()`. What is the fastest and most efficient way to return an array `combi()` of all possible triangles that can be drawn from those points, in VBA?

I have put together a simple script, and it works a charm for a small number of points. But it slows down exponentially as I add more points. Below is a simplified version of what I have.

Please note: you will see in my code that I am doing some basic checks to ensure all vertices in the triangle are different. I am also splitting the points in each and ordering them by 'size'. The reason I am doing that is that I will need to remove duplicate triangles. Of course, if your proposed implementation finds the triangles without the duplicates then that would be optimal

**My code:**

```
Sub find_triangles()

    Dim arr(6) As Variant
    Dim combi() As Variant


    arr(0) = 1
    arr(1) = 2
    arr(2) = 3
    arr(3) = 4
    arr(4) = 5
    arr(5) = 6
    'arr(x)= x ... etc.

    ReDim combi(0)

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
       For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
          For k = 1 To UBound(arr)
             If Not i = j And Not j = k And Not i = k Then

                m = Array(i, j, k)

                ReDim temp(2)

                temp(0) = Application.Small(m, 1)
                temp(1) = Application.Small(m, 2)
                temp(2) = Application.Small(m, 3)

                combi(UBound(combi)) = temp(0) & "-" & temp(1) & "-" & temp(2)
                ReDim Preserve combi(UBound(combi) + 1)

             End If
          Next
       Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How does it handle, not resizing `combi` each time.  Do you mean to use `arr` in the code somewhere too?

Comment: Hi Nathan. The reason I resize is because I don't know the ultimate length of the array! Would that make a significant difference?

Comment: Im not sure, you dont really give any indication of the size of arr, or use it, so not sure where the lag is coming in.

Comment: The three loops that are doing all the work are not using arr(). They just make a reference to its length as a parameter of the loop. So arr() is not the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Noobster,

I can see several performance bottlenecks in your code.

As @Nathan_Sav suggested, repeatedly resizing `combi` is an issue. Far better would be to initially declare it with a limit of 100 say, and then increase the limit as needed;

As part of your looping, you are repeatedly checking the size of `arr` to see how many times you must loop for i, j and k. Far better would be to store the size of `arr` in a variable, and use this in the loop.

You may also find that nesting the if statements rather than performing them all at once helps. So if `i<>j`, the code doesn't need to check if `j<>k` or `i<>k`.

Finally, I think that I can see a way to improve the logic to only get unique triangles, assuming that "1-2-3" and "1-3-2" are the same. Rather than looping j from 1 to the limit, loop j from i+1 to the limit, and loop k from j+1 to the limit. This both drastically reduces the number of iterations of the code, and also removes the need to check for equality. Something like this perhaps:

```
intUpper = UBound(arr)
ReDim combi(0 To 100)
For intLoop1 = 1 To intUpper
    For intLoop2 = intLoop1 + 1 To intUpper
        For intLoop3 = intLoop2 + 1 To intUpper
            combi(intCount) = intLoop1 & "-" & intLoop2 & "-" & intLoop3
            intCount = intCount + 1
            If intCount Mod 100 = 0 Then ReDim Preserve combi(0 To intCount + 100)
        Next intLoop3
    Next intLoop2
Next intLoop1
If intCount > 0 Then ReDim Preserve combi(0 To intCount)
```

Regards,

Comment: Your suggested solution is extremely efficient and sophisticated.